# Chrome Extension to click on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, click, refresh

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will click a link when the page of a certain site is loaded/refresh. So far I have not been able to get it to work, I've tried different code snippets from different sources but no matter what I try it still doesnt do anything.

My manifest looks like this --

```
 {
  "name": "SITENAME",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://SITENAME.com/*"],
      "js": ["sitenamelink.js"]
    }
  ], "permissions": [
    "tabs" , "*://SITENAME.com/*"
  ]
}
```

The site will have random dynamic variables appended to the end of it, such as "sitename.com/product/model...etc. etc." so theres really no way for it to be predictable, only way would to find the page url and update the extension everytime which is not something I want to have to do.

I was trying to keep the js coding clean and simple and the js I have now is --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addToCartLink').trigger('click');
});
```

I also tried this --

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('a#addToCartLink')[0].click();
});
```

and this --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#addToCartLink')[0].click();
});
```

The page that has the link, has it coded as such -- `<a id="addToCartLink" href="javascript:addToCart()" onclick="showBubble(this)" onmouseout="hideBubble()"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>`

Im not sure how to inspect it to see where my code is failing because when I inspect with chrome, it only shows the js errors from that page's coding.

So what am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here's a test page, the size is selected if you follow this link, and now only requires for the add to cart link to be clicked. -- Test Page

Comment: call .click() on the dom node itself. `document.getElementById('addToCartLink').click()`

Comment: or better yet, skip the click entirely. `showBubble(document.getElementById('addToCartLink'));`

Comment: @KevinB but if I skip the click wont that just make the bubble appear instead of adding the item to cart?

Comment: You're right, i missed the href javascript. Click method it is then. Or, you could execute the addToCart method too.

Comment: I tried changing the js file to have only that line - document.getElementById('addToCartLink').click(); but it didnt work.

Comment: Well yea, you still need to wait for the element to exist.

Comment: I also tried this `$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById('addToCartLink').click();
});` but it didnt work

Comment: Are you injecting jQuery ? It doesn't seem so from your manifest. Besides, you don't have to wait for document to be ready, since by default the content-script is injected as soon as the document is idle (meaning it has fully loaded). BTW, it might help if you revealed the actual name of this mysterious site...

Comment: @ExpertSystem ok, I dont think its injecting the jquery. And its not a mystery site, Im trying to figure it out to work with any site. But if you need an example that Im using its - eastbay.com

Comment: Why don't you give an example usage ? There isno such link in the main page and even when a specific product page is visited and I programmatically click the link, there is bubble saying you should select sise. Please, be more presice on your exact requirements and context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sample extension (see code below) worked fine for me.
E.g.: Visiting the **[Test Page](http://www.eastbay.com/product/model:194958/sku:55035003/nike-kobe-viii-system-mens/grey/purple/?cm=GLOBAL%20SEARCH%3a%20KEYWORD%20SEARCH#sku=55035003&size=12.0)** you provided, the `ADD TO CART` link is clicked and the item is added to cart.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*.sitename.com/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

**content.js**:

```
document.getElementById('addToCartLink').click();
```

Comment: I have another question maybe you can answer. I was wondering if it's possible to choose a option from a select menu and then excecute the above answer after? Something like this `document.getElementById("#product_sizes").children("option[value='12.0']").prop('selected',true)`

Comment: Almost anything is possible. Your imagination is the limit :) The how depends on what exactly you want and what the DOM looks like, so if you can't find something relevant here in SO, post a question with all the necessary info.